# how to add custom information from database on email for each customer

Tags: magento2

In my emails only show the product name but i want show all the information comes in emails form database table name (tbl_customer_subs)how to do it?[image]

Comment: that's for the order email template?

Comment: I wat to add some custom information in email. how to do that

Comment: Which information you have stored in table tbl_customer_subs?

Answer (score 0):

Since there's a lot of Emails i will take for example the order Email,
If you want to set custom variable's inside your Email from a custom table and then display them you should declare in your module:

**Events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
 <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
     <observer name="order-add-custom-field-data" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Emailtemplatevars"/>
 </event>
</config>
```

**app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\Emailtemplatevars.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
 
class Emailtemplatevars implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
 protected $helper;
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 {
     $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $transport['Customvariable1'] = 'Your Values...';
             //add multiple parameter
 }
}
```

And then in your theme you'll place the html used for the order_new Email:
**app\design\frontend\Themes\Yourtheme\Magento_Sales\email\order_new.html**

Inside order_new there's this code:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Your %store_name order confirmation" store_name=$store.frontend_name}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order_data.email_customer_note|escape|nl2br":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.shipping_description":"Shipping Description",
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message",
"var created_at_formatted":"Order Created At (datetime)",
"var store.frontend_name":"Store Frontend Name",
"var store_phone":"Store Phone",
"var store_email":"Store Email",
"var store_hours":"Store Hours",
"var this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1])":"Customer Account URL",
"var order_data.is_not_virtual":"Order Type",
"var order":"Order",
"var order_data.customer_name":"Customer Name",
"var customVariable1":"Custom Variable 1",
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<p>{{var customVariable1}}</p>
<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order_data.customer_name}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.frontend_name}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$created_at_formatted |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order_data.email_customer_note}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order_data.email_customer_note|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order_data.is_not_virtual}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order_data.is_not_virtual}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```